# How can I fill a nested table?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following code:

```
     FOR rw IN myCur(id) LOOP
          BEGIN
             SELECT DISTINCT ingredient, f_ing_descr(1, ingredient, 0), syntypepack.fGetSyn(ingredient, 700512) CAS, syntypepack.fGetSyn(ingredient, 700513) EC
             INTO lnIngredient, lsIngredientDescription, lnCAS, lnEC
             FROM ING
             WHERE part = 'FSI'
             AND rev = 1
             ORDER BY quantity DESC;
```

I want to fill a nested-table with all the values returned from this statement and afterwards add all the rows to a table.

I already have this:

```
    TYPE ingCasEc IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
    lnTableSyns ingCasEc ;
    lnTableSyns := ingCasEc(lnIngredient, lnCAS, lnEC);
```

can anyone please help me with this issue, i can figure the add all rows out, just the nested-table is my weakness.

Thanks for all your help and advice.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me what you are trying to do here..  Why would you be putting different column values into the same nested table?  Can you explain what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Because it is required of me to retrieve these specific column values as they are, and then import them into a self defined api. This was suggested as the easiest way to do this as i would need to temporarily store these values and then clear the table i need to insert them into and then add the temporarily stored column values. I just want to add those variables into a nested table, thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
    TYPE int_rec IS RECORD
    (
        lnIngredient            VARCHAR2(30)
    ,   lsIngredientDescription VARCHAR2(30)
    ,   lnCAS                   VARCHAR2(30)
    ,   lnEC                    VARCHAR2(30)
    );

    TYPE ingCasEc IS TABLE OF int_rec;
    lnTableSyns ingCasEc ;
BEGIN
     SELECT DISTINCT ingredient, f_ing_descr(1, ingredient, 0), syntypepack.fGetSyn(ingredient, 700512) CAS, syntypepack.fGetSyn(ingredient, 700513) EC
     BULK COLLECT INTO lnTableSyns
     FROM ING
     WHERE part = 'FSI'
     AND rev = 1
     ORDER BY quantity DESC;  
END;
```